# how can I draw it in the Venn diagram- A ⊕ B ⊆ (A ⊕ C) ∪ (B ⊕ C)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using Venn diagrams, prove the relationships:

A ⊕ B ⊆ (A ⊕ C) ∪ (B ⊕ C)
thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome! There is a `venndiagram` package. Your notation is also not unambiguous (to me), you may want to clarify what you mean by `⊕` in this context where you also use `∪`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: `⊕` is exclusive or (XOR).

Comment: @OnlyTheParanoidSurvive I know what it normally means but in this combination it is a bit unusual for my taste. Also, would you mind letting the OP respond? If I had to guess I would have guessed in the same way you did but it is better to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of your question has been anticipated for decades.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-venn}

\def\right{%
        \psVenn[bgcircle=false,fgcolor=green!30](1;150)(1;270)(1;30){2}{123456}     
        \uput{2.2}[150](1;150){$A$}
        \uput{2.2}[30](1;30){$B$}
        \uput{2.2}[270](1;270){$C$}}

\def\left{%
        \pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=green!30]{\pscircle(1;150){2}\pscircle(1;30){2}}       
        \uput{2.2}[150](1;150){$A$}
        \uput{2.2}[30](1;30){$B$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-8,-3.5)(8,3)
    \rput(-5,0){\left}
    \rput(5,0){\right}
    \rput(0,0){\psscalebox{5}{$\subseteq$}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]